# combine two temporary tables into one table, but keep all the column names

Tags: mysql

I need to create two temporary tables, then join them together into one table and keep all of the column names for both tables and the data.  Using Mysql

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tenant_invoices
    SELECT * FROM invoices

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tenant_payments
    SELECT * FROM payments
```

How do I go about doing this using MYSQL?

Thanks.

Comment: please show us the two table schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create the two temp tables, you can use a `CROSS JOIN` to join the tables together:

```
select ti.*, tp.*
from tenant_invoices ti
cross join tenant_payments tp
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29ea4/2)

`CROSS JOIN` will work if there is no field to join the tables.  If you have a field to join on then you can use an `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select ti.*, tp.*
from tenant_invoices ti
inner join tenant_payments tp
  on ti.account_id = tp.account_id
```

or

```
select ti.*, tp.*
from tenant_invoices ti
left join tenant_payments tp
  on ti.account_id = tp.account_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3036d/5)

Comment: Thanks.  I added that, but it's duplicating the results.  Instead of 8 rows I get 16 rows?

Comment: Do your tables have a field that can join them?  Like Invoice.id = payment.id?

Comment: I have "account_id"  I updated the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3036d/2     But not sure I've got it right.

Comment: @Ronedog If you have a field that can join the tables, you can use `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` -  see this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3036d/4 -- see my edit